# developer platform for Windows RT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-rt

Can you make me clear which delevoper platform I can use for delevop Apps for Windows RT (not full Windows 8!). Are some projects templates in Visual Studio which are allowed me to use only WinRt without .NEt during my development on c# and xaml.

Comment: The non ARM Windows 8 version (Pro or Normal), All Modern apps are RT apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual C#/VB/C++/JS|Windows Store app templates (Blank App, Grid App, Split App) are for apps that will run on Windows RT and any other Windows 8. You can use .NET on Windows RT, but if you don't want to - you can also use C++ or JavaScript. Note that Windows RT is the SKU of Windows that runs on ARM tablets, while WinRT or Windows Runtime is the new generation development platform for Windows. Also note, that while most parts of Windows Runtime can be used only by Windows Store apps, some can be used by both Windows Store and Desktop apps, some can only be used by desktop apps and I think some parts of the old WinAPI/Win32 might be accessible to Windows Store apps too. MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) states which APIs apply to which types of applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516).

More info on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211386#part3_learntoolsandtemplates).

The project templates are available under `Windows Store` category under `Visual C#` in `New Project` in Visual Studio.